# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 incoming Emails SMTP wont delete Drop Folder

Tags: incoming-email

I set up a SharePoint 2010 Foundation with Exchange 2010.
I installed on my SharePoint Server an SMTP Server on my Exchange i set a Connector to SharePoint SMPT. My SharePoint receive Emails and place it correctly in my libary but after 5 minutes the same Email is placed again with a number cause i dont want overwrite files. I looked in the Drop Folder of my SMTP an the Emails are still in there. Is there any Option i can set that after SharePoint placed it in libary it will delete in drop Folder ?

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you assign the correct permissions to the drop folder? Review the requirements in the article underneath - refer to the "Configure permissions to the e-mail drop folder" section:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947(v=office.14).aspx

The WSS_Admin_WPG group had to have full control, the WSS_WPG group has to have Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, and Read permissions.

Comment: The user for timerservice needed permission.